# Javascript shrinking header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create a shrinking header. I've tried the example below but it's not working. I want to shrink the header element when I scroll down. The header should shrink pixel by pixel and if it reaches the height of 80 pixel it should stop from shrinking.
This is an example of what I want: https://kriesi.at/themes/enfold/

Thanks for your help.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {header_scroll()};

function header_scroll(){
  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 1 || document.body.scrollTop > 1 ) {
    document.getElementById('page').classList.add("smallheader");
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('page').classList.remove("smallheader")
  }
}
```

```css
#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    background-color: green;
    transition: 0.4s;
    z-index: 5;
}

.smallheader #header{
     height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">
      <p>content</p>
  </div>
  <p>content</p> 
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p> 
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: heres an example https://kriesi.at/themes/enfold/

Comment: The div you've attched the scroll listener never triggers the said event. You should also explain what you expect your code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: Why is there a PHP tag?

Comment: @Mehdi Maybe somebody solve it with php.

Comment: Can you use jQuery? If so I can post a simple solution

Comment: @Teemu Yeah i see thanks i forgot some code. I tryed to explain. my code snipet is how my code is working and in the link you see the way how it should work.

Comment: @JordanQuartermain yeah i can use jQuery

Comment: But after the edit the head shrinks ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own solution now:

```js
window.onscroll = function() {      

  var pixel = window.scrollY;
  var newheader = 200 - pixel; //100 is the high of the header i can't use document.getelementById         because there some weird problems
    
  if (newheader>70) { //70 its the smallest height of the header
    document.getElementById('header').setAttribute("style","height:"+newheader+"px");
  }
 }
```

```css
#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="page">
  <div id="header">
      <p>content</p>
  </div>
  <p>content</p> 
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p> 
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be your desired behavior

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (scroll >= 80) {
        $("#header").addClass("smallheader");
    } 
    else if ( scroll < 80 ) {
        $("#header").removeClass("smallheader");
    }
});
```

```css
#header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    position: fixed;
    top:0;
    background-color: green;
    transition: 0.4s;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  #header.smallheader {
     height: 80px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
  <div id="header" onscroll="header_scroll()">
      <p>content</p>
      <p>content</p>
  </div>
  <p>content</p> 
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p> 
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
    <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p> 
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p> 
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p>
  <p>content</p><p>content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but its not the way i want. here is the problem when i scroll with the mouse wheel the header jump to the small height and when im on the bottom of the page and i scroll up the header is getting bigger but he should only get bigger when i on the top of the page.

Comment: hm.. no it does exactly the same like my script. it hat exactrly 1 point in your code 80 pixel and if you reach these 80 pixel it shrink but i want from the first pixel i scroll to start shrinking but if i only scroll 3 pixel i want that the header shrink only these 3 pixel